# How can I create a new collection in mongodb with fields mentioned?

Tags: json, mongodb

Am looking for clean and efficient ways to create a new collection from any existing collection based on a some filters. I've to do this many times in a day and currently am printing the filtered results to log and storing this as json and again importing this to collection(which is surely a long and weird way to do this, I know ).
Any help would be great.

Tried using:

```js
db.getCollection('reviews').find({},{"asin":1,summary:1,reviewText:1,_id:0}).forEach( function(x){ db.subset.save(x)})
```

This is failing with error

[image]

Comment: It would be good if you share your existing code

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
db.mySourceCollection.find().forEach( function(x){ db.theDestinationCollection.save(x)});
```

Simply adding your criterias for the filters and you could even use projection to remove some fields...

EDIT: Thanks to your screenshot I've been able to figure out you are using robomongo... This issue is already filed [here](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1106). I suggest you read through it, apparently a fix should be in place on the latest version but I do not use it so I didn't test myself.

EDIT 2: You might get lucky and work around it using a bulk operation...

```
var bulk = db.mySourceCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
db.mySourceCollection.find().forEach( function(x){ bulk.insert(x)});
bulk.execute();
```

Using this technique, you might end up luckier as it will be sped up and will not reach the timeout... I am uncertain of what happens if the client disconnects during the execute but I think we can safely assume that the write will continue. That's what makes it interesting.

Comment: Sorry that i didnt update in question, tried this earlier also.. but this is failing with an error https://imagebin.ca/v/3TE3aUStb24M